# Plausible Language Origins and Meaning of The Puerto Rican Jibaro Word "lelo"?

Tags: spanish

> **Question**: What might be a plausible language origin of the word, "***lelo***" as used in traditional [jibaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Puerto_Rico#J%C3%ADbaro_music) musical form of Puerto Rico.

The word ***lelo*** is intensively used in the introduction of jibaro folkloric music of Puerto Rico. A classic example can be found in a traditional musical song form known as a *decima*:  [Florencio "Ramito" Morales Ramos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florencio_Morales_Ramos): [Sies Con Decimas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyStmuI1xwE).

Curiously while tracing the origin of the word "*fogon*" a common outdoor cooking set up in Puerto Rico,  I came across idiophones of the Basque language. Under the alphabetical listing L there is "lelo" - ***[same old story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ideophones_in_Basque#L)***; which compared to the musical form seems right.

Comment: While I wouldn't expect to be able to answer this anyway, I am surprised that you have not given the meaning of the word _lelo_ in the songs.

Comment: @ColinFine excellent point. I do not know the meaning. I will edit the question and ask for a possible meaning and origin.

Answer (score 1):

It is plausibly not a word per se, but a sound evocative of singing. You encounter it in English ("lalalala"), and in Finnic languages the root "sing" is often something like *laulu-* (Saami joik is mostly compose of lu-lu-lu). "Ululate" is a Latin-based English word (Latin *ululo*) which is a kind of singing, and in a number of Bantu languages there is a verb *luluta* meaning "to ululate". So it could have an iconic, sound-symbolic origin.